# Julia 0.4.7: How to catch SIGTERM

Tags: julia, sigterm

I am getting the following stacktrace after SIGTERM (not SIGINT) event in a julia-0.4.7 script:

```
signal (15): Terminate
write at /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x2ade16a02893)
uv_write2 at /path/to/home/julia/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
jl_uv_write at /path/to/home/julia/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
uv_write at ./stream.jl:951
buffer_or_write at ./stream.jl:972
write at ./stream.jl:1011
print at ./char.jl:47
unknown function (ip: 0x2ade1e06d0a2)
jl_apply_generic at /path/to/home/julia/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
print at strings/io.jl:18
jl_apply_generic at /path/to/home/julia/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
jl_f_apply at /path/to/home/julia/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
println at strings/io.jl:25
jl_apply_generic at /path/to/home/julia/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
anonymous at /path/to/home/test.jl:4
unknown function (ip: 0x2ade169c5b13)
unknown function (ip: 0x2ade169c672c)
jl_load at /path/to/home/julia/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
include at ./boot.jl:261
jl_apply_generic at /path/to/home/julia/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:333
jl_apply_generic at /path/to/home/julia/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
process_options at ./client.jl:284
_start at ./client.jl:378
unknown function (ip: 0x2ade1e05ae79)
jl_apply_generic at /path/to/home/julia/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x401c87)
unknown function (ip: 0x40186f)
__libc_start_main at /lib64/libc.so.6 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x4018b5)
```

So, how do I catch it? Looks like sth is broken in my Julia binaries, isn't it? Is there a similar way to catch SIGTERM like for SIGINT? i.e.:

```
ccall(:jl_exit_on_sigint, Void, (Cint,), 0)
try
    ...
catch ex
    println("caught something")
    if isa(ex, InterruptException)
        println("it was an interrupt")
    end
end
```

I am using Cent-OS 6.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't, see [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/14675). The thing you reference, `jl_exit_on_sigint` is a C function written in `julia/src/signal-handling.c`. At present, they have not written a handler for `SIGTERM`, so adding your own handler would mean changing Julia's base, and they have not exposed any API for handling signals in general. This is largely because there isn't a way to have a consistent way of doing signal handling across threads without a large performance hit.